# Using Where clause in case mysql

Tags: mysql, switch-statement, case, where-clause, between

Below is my query and i am getting total number of related status values correctly. But i need those values in a specific time range. For getting total values below is my query.

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE 
     WHEN `status` = 'saved_for_review' THEN 1
     ELSE 0
   END) AS SavedCases,
SUM(CASE 
     WHEN STATUS = 'send_to_warehouse' THEN 1
     ELSE 0
   END) AS SendtoWareshouse,
SUM(CASE 
     WHEN STATUS = 'send_to_cep' THEN 1
     ELSE 0
   END) AS SendtoCEP,
   SUM(CASE 
     WHEN STATUS = 'Successful' THEN 1
     ELSE 0
   END) AS Closed 
FROM table_details
```

But i need values in specific time range  like

```
where date(created_on) between '20160701' and '20160901'
```

How can i add this where clause to the above query. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any sql tutorial would have told you that the `where` clause goes after the `from` clause.

Comment: Delete `But i need values in specific time range like` and there you go.

Comment: Previously i gave some alias to the table thats why i didn't get that . Added my answer. Please revert the down vote.

Comment: You should delete the entire question along with your answer, it is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all just writing `SUM(status='saved_for_review') SavedCases` works and is much simpler and faster. As for the `WHERE` clause, you just add it after the `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(status = 'saved_for_review') SavedCases,
    SUM(status = 'send_to_warehouse') SendtoWarehouse,
    SUM(status = 'send_to_cep') SendtoCEP,
    SUM(status = 'Successful') Closed 
FROM table_details
WHERE DATE(created_on) BETWEEN '20160701' AND '20160901'
```